# GA4 migration for multiple websites, should I continue to use multiple property IDs as in the legacy GA?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

We are currently using two legacy Google Analytics property IDs on two websites

- GA_1. http://www.aaa.com
- GA_2. http://www.bbb.com

However, we also have an app, but it is using a single Firebase ID (thus linked to another GA4 ID - GA4_1).

Now, as legacy GA will stop working in June. I have two choices

1. Create another 2 GA4 property IDs (e.g. GA4_2, GA4_3), replace the old one (GA_1, GA_2)
2. Re-use the existing GA4_1 from the app

Which one is better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are ok depending on the situation.

The simplest way to decide is by the user journeys. If there are journeys from one domain to another, analyzing the whole user journey would be quite annoying. Answering questions like: `When a user comes from site A to site B and subscribes to this a particular service on site B, which source was it that brought this subscriber to site A?` would be difficult if the data is split by different properties.

Similar thing happens when you have an app user opening a webview to a help article on the site. That webview will be tracked by your web GTM, but the rest of the user's session will be in the app. If they're split across different properties, you will have troubles joining the data.

This presumes you actually use GA's interface for analysis and reporting. If you ETL the data to BQ and then use something else to analyze it on top of it, then you may have minor reasons to split the account across properties. If nothing else, then to increase property limits of GA4.

In short, it's better to use one GA4 property, the same you get data to from your Firebase. But keep it in different Data Streams just in case.

Make sure to configure your web streams to merge client and session ids across domains if your sites live on different top-level domains, which is what it looks like from your example. Unlike GA UA, GA4 now has the cross-domain tracking settings in GA4 rather than GTM.

Answer (score 0):

For managing multiple websites and an app, it is recommended to use separate GA4 property IDs for each website and the app. This will allow you to track each property separately and get detailed insights into the performance of each property.

In your case, since you have two websites and an app, you can create two new GA4 property IDs for the websites (e.g. GA4_2, GA4_3) and link them to the respective websites. You can continue to use the existing GA4_1 property ID for the app.

By using separate property IDs, you can easily manage each property and get accurate data. Moreover, you can set up custom reports and dashboards specific to each property, which will help you gain valuable insights and make informed decisions.

In summary, it is recommended to create separate GA4 property IDs for each website and app to track their performance accurately and manage them effectively.